# MonoTouch Update Beta Chan / mono_handle_native_sigsegv

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, segmentation-fault

My app crashes on my device with the exception mono_handle_native_sigsegv

I read that this is fixed in 5.1.1+ betas. How can I update my MonoTouch to 5.1.1+?

Currently Im using MonoTouch 5.08 and MonoDevelop 2.8.  I dont see the option to update on beta channels.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in MD --> Preferences, under Updates, check the "unstable developer updates" and then select alpha or beta

MT 5.2.1 is the current beta, I believe.